# Specify apt-get a minimum version to be installed

Tags: apt

You can specify a specific version to install a package this way: `apt-get install pkg=version`.

But can you specify a minimum version?

For example, I want at least gcc 8, but I'm ok with gcc 9.

Something like this (obviously doesn't work): `apt-get install pkg>=version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt`’s options on packages allow the user to choose among the various versions of a package which `apt` knows about; they don’t allow the user to specify general package constraints.

The simplest approach to achieve what you’re after is to use `equivs`. Write the following to a file, say `mingcc`:

```
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 4.5.0

Package: gcc-8-or-later
Depends: gcc (>= 4:8)
Description: dependency package ensuring GCC 8 or later is installed
 This meta-package ensures that GCC 8 or later is installed.
```

Then build the package:

```
equivs-build mingcc
```

This will generate a package, `gcc-8-or-later_1.0_all.deb`, either in the current directory or in `$TMP`. You can install it with `apt`:

```
apt install ./gcc-8-or-later_1.0_all.deb
```

The installation will only work if GCC 8 or later is available.

(The `gcc` meta-packages in Debian and Ubuntu use an epoch, currently at 4, hence `>= 4:8`.)

Answer (score 5):

Sice apt 1.9 (released on 17 Jun 2019), you can use `apt(-get) satisfy` like:

```
sudo apt-get satisfy "foo (>= 1.0), bar (>= 2.0)"
```

The dependency string syntax is described here:

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#syntax-of-relationship-fields